# How to uninstall all non-default software?

Tags: 14.04, uninstall, restore

I want to essentially reset Ubuntu 14.04 to factory settings, but I want to keep my unity preferences and my python packages. I'm thinking I should just uninstall all software that aren't factory installed.

How would I go about doing this, or is there an alternative you suggest?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages May help...?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking is system restore to as passive state.
There is a package available but it must be installed and have a screenshot of state.
check this page to get help in installing Time Shift and configuration.
[Time Shift](http://www.unixmen.com/timeshift-restore-linux-desktops-previous-state/)